# GooglePlus::RequestError: Invalid Credentials

Tags: rubygems, google-plus, omniauth

I`m getting 'GooglePlus::RequestError: Invalid Credentials' with google plus rails gem.

Can't understand since when I use it to sign in an user it works fine, but Im also using the credentials retrieved to display some info about the user, then, even if it works temporarily, after a day or two I get this error:

'GooglePlus::RequestError: Invalid Credentials'

My helper code:

```
def google_friends(user)
    auth = user.social_auths.where(provider: 'google').first

    if auth
      begin
        GooglePlus.api_key = ENV['GOOGLE_KEY']
        client = GooglePlus::Person.get(auth.uid, :access_token => auth.token)
        client.emails.first["value"]
      rescue
        ''
      end
    else
      ''
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What scopes are you requesting with your login?

Comment: There are none... I'm storing the uid and token and using it later to retrieve the latest info on user's social...

Comment: acccess tokens expire after 1 hour, you need to use the refreshtoken to get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give **access_type=offline** while authorization. And also you need to use the refreshtoken to refresh to get new access token for your operation.The access token have expiery time. So if you want to use your acess token you have to refresh it.otherwise it will be an invalid token after the expiry.